# Print Fixed Decimals using errs() in llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

How to print fixed point decimals using errs() output stream of llvm.

For example if now if am doing errs()<<3.3; it is showing in scientific notation. I want it in decimal notation. I don't want to print with cout, but with errs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `format` function from `include/llvm/Support/Format.h` to create C-printf-like strings:

```
errs() << format("%.3f\n", 3.3);
```

etc.

Comment: thanks! I looked at documentation but couldn't find it.